# Выбрать данные из JSON (php) при помощи дрогого json

Tags: javascript, php, массивы, json, циклы

Есть два json

```
{
    "7":{"name_items":"СТЕЙК ИЗ ГОВЯДИНЫ С ОВОЩАМИ","price":"700","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598253756.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"174","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
    "8":{"name_items":"СТЕЙК ИЗ СВИНИНЫ С ОВОЩАМИ","price":"600","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598253968.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"326","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
    "9":{"name_items":"СВИНИНА НА КОСТОЧКЕ ЗАПЕЧЕННАЯ","price":"600","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254091.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"361","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
   "10":{"name_items":"ШАШЛЫК ИЗ КУРИНЫХ БЕДЕР","price":"350","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254457.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"412","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
   "11":{"name_items":"ШААШЛЫК ИЗ КУРИНЫХ КРЫЛЬЕВ","price":"330","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254623.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"358","weight":null,"restaurant":"Лайм","Stop":"0"},

}
```

и второй

```
{"7":1,"9":1,"11":1}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести значения свойств позиций используя второй json содержащий их id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На JS можно конечно использовать методы бегающие по ключам/индексам, но я предпочитаю скорость работы скрипта, поэтому ниже - через создание копии объекта и удаление из него ненужного в один проход.

```js
const source = `{
    "7":{"name_items":"СТЕЙК ИЗ ГОВЯДИНЫ С ОВОЩАМИ","price":"700","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598253756.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"174","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
    "8":{"name_items":"СТЕЙК ИЗ СВИНИНЫ С ОВОЩАМИ","price":"600","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598253968.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"326","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
    "9":{"name_items":"СВИНИНА НА КОСТОЧКЕ ЗАПЕЧЕННАЯ","price":"600","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254091.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"361","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
   "10":{"name_items":"ШАШЛЫК ИЗ КУРИНЫХ БЕДЕР","price":"350","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254457.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"412","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
   "11":{"name_items":"ШААШЛЫК ИЗ КУРИНЫХ КРЫЛЬЕВ","price":"330","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254623.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"358","weight":null,"restaurant":"Лайм","Stop":"0"}
}`;
const select = `{"7":1,"9":1,"11":1}`;
const sourceParsed = JSON.parse(source);
const selectParsed = JSON.parse(select);
const result = {...sourceParsed};
Object.keys(result).forEach(key => !selectParsed[key] && delete(result[key]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: А зачем копировать объект, а потом еще его изменять? Не проще ли (и быстрее) использовать Array.map и просто создать новый массив?

Comment: @www3b На больших объемах данных создание нового массива медленнее, чем удаление указателей в существующем объекте. Ответ исключительно на личном опыте, но для заведомо небольших данных можно и через `reduce` сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$list = '{
    "7":{"name_items":"СТЕЙК ИЗ ГОВЯДИНЫ С ОВОЩАМИ","price":"700","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598253756.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"174","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
    "8":{"name_items":"СТЕЙК ИЗ СВИНИНЫ С ОВОЩАМИ","price":"600","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598253968.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"326","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
    "9":{"name_items":"СВИНИНА НА КОСТОЧКЕ ЗАПЕЧЕННАЯ","price":"600","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254091.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"361","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
   "10":{"name_items":"ШАШЛЫК ИЗ КУРИНЫХ БЕДЕР","price":"350","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254457.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"412","weight":null,"restaurant":"","Stop":"0"},
   "11":{"name_items":"ШААШЛЫК ИЗ КУРИНЫХ КРЫЛЬЕВ","price":"330","description":"","photo":"images\/positions\/1598254623.jpg","type":"Тандыр","calories":"358","weight":null,"restaurant":"Лайм","Stop":"0"}
}';

$values = '{"7":1,"9":1,"11":1}';

$listArr = json_decode($list, true);
$valuesArr = json_decode($values, true);

$result = [];

foreach($valuesArr as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = $listArr[$key];
}

print_r($result);
```